# Display product attribute in checkout page not working in magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, checkout

I have added an attribute shape .

```
attribute code -> shape
attribute label -> Shape
values -> diamond, square, round
input type -> multi select
```

Now I want to display the attribute shape details in checkout page. I have tried the following code in `app\design\frontend\mytheme\mytheme\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml`

My code as follows:

```
echo $_item->getShape();
```

Unfortunately nothing is displayed. How can  I do this. Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you tried to get Shape from the model Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item. Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way.

Please try this solution:

```
$product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
echo $product->getShape();
```